# The best way to send messages between different devices?

Tags: mysql, apache, sockets, http

Im about to develop a hobby project where i want to send different kind of data between different devices (pc, mac, iphone, android).

Im asking for a little help among the way and that is when it comes to message passing.

What is the best way to send (for example Strings) between different systems and languages. Mostly it will only be strigns sent.

Im thinking of a web server that waits for different kind of messages (via socket) and sends this to all devices.

In other case i thought about creating a database where i enter different kind of messages in different tables and just wait for the latest stuff to arrive (for example every second).

How would you guys do?

Was i unclear by my question? Then please respond and i will try to explain better.

Comment: So ... a chat client? Or some sort of message inbox?

Comment: Hi

No not a chat client more like queue system. You enter something and it's get pushed to a queue and all connected devices gets to know who's active and who's next in queue.

Database feels most logic but how i should you do for receiving the latest stuff?

I mean maybe you add something to the queue and then if another device adds something i need to get that change on my device as well.

Sorry for my english, i hope you understand